# Database Deadlock occurs, but why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, transactions, deadlock

I can't figure this one out, think i have stared my self blind on the problem.

I have the following scenario on MsSql server 2012.

In 10 threads (C# + NHibernate) i do this:

1. Begin transaction (ReadCommitted)

   1. Select **count(*)** from MyTable1 where ... (compare on columns which do not have index, so this would proberbly cause a complete table scan)
   2. Insert into MyTable1 ...
   3. Insert into MyTable2 ...
   4. Repeat a,b,c 100 times.
2. Commit transaction

The data used is unique for each thread so one thread cannot create the same insert as another thread.

**This results in a deadlock.**

If i use **ReadUncommitted** transaction it works flawlessly since there is no read/write locks at all.

But I cant seem to wrap head around how this can cause a deadlock and im pretty sure this is a textbook example of a deadlock.

Can someone clearify how this can cause a deadlock?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far; it will help in debugging the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the "deadlock" is not just _really_ slow processing? The process of creating and releasing locks will cause a significant hit in performance. How do you know it is deadlock for sure?

Comment: I get a deadlock exception.

Comment: As Brian stated above, without seeing the code involved for your DAL in the process of it actually running through a scenario to test for a `Deadlock` we won't be able to assist you.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant or off-topic. But would it be an alternative to create a stored procedure that locks, executes and commits the data? The database itself handle the transactions and lock/commit handling and the code operates with the stored proc.

Comment: It is much more likely that you are getting blocking, lock timeouts and query timeouts than that you are getting actual deadlocks.  Especially because the transaction that you describe above *10 threads is virtually guaranteed to cause severe blocking.  But either way, scanning a table multiple times within a transaction is begging for severe blocking and/or deadlocks.

Comment: I realise that this is not a good approach at all, but its a legacy system im optimizing for perfomance and i cant get around the scan every iteration unfortunately :(. Im looking for a justification for using ReadUncommitted which solves the deadlock issue. But i cant dó that until i can explain in words how this causes a deadlock :).

Comment: Would it be possible to do the following: (1) begin transaction, (2) run 100 selects, (3) run 100 inserts into MyTable1, (4) run 100 inserts into MyTable2, (5) commit?  Since you are touching the tables in a certain order without going back it should alleviate your issue.

Comment: It would but it would require quite a lot of work. The ReadUncommitted transaction is an easy way to fix it but it makes mé a bit puzzeled since i cant explain the deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the database was configured for SnapshotReadComitted. But I did not know (neebie on the system).

As soon as I realized this I was able to solve the issue :).

Thx for all your help :).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

- Thread (a) executes step 1.1 (Read MyTable1)
- Thread (b) executes step 1.1 (Read MyTable1)
- Thread (a) executes step 1.2 (Write MyTable1)
- Thread (b) executes step 1.2 (Write MyTable1)

Next iteration...

- Thread (a) tries to execute step 1.1 by has to wait until Thread (b) commits
- Thread (b) tries to execute step 1.1 by has to wait until Thread (a) commits

Deadlock

Comment: If you are correct is it then safe for me to use ReadUncommitted transactions to solve the deadlock or might i run into something worse down the Line?

Comment: Without seeing your code I cannot say for sure.  However, if the result of your query affects your insert, you may run into issues down the line.  In the long term, your best best might be to "bulkify" your operations... What I mean by this is to insert 100 rows at a time into a temp table or local XML variable and work from there.  You can most likely convert your 100 selects + 200 inserts into 1 select and 2 inserts against a temporary row set.  SQL Server will be happier too :)